# Error parsing the JSON file using Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am getting the error while parsing the the following JSON file. If anybody please help me out, highly appreciated!

```
{"Name":"Abc", "Author":"fgd", "Company List":{"Company":"C1","Companyone":"Compa2"}}
```

Here is my code:-

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/Users/abcdefgh/Documents/File1.txt"));

       JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Name");
        String author = (String) jsonObject.get("Author");
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Author: " + author);
       // JSONArray companyList= new JSONArray();
        //companyList.add(obj);
      JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Company List");


        System.out.println("Company List:");
       /* for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
            System.out.println(companyList.get(i));

        }
        */Iterator<String> iterator = companyList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
```

Output:-

> Name: Abc
>
> Author: fgd
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be
>   cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray     at
>   com.selenium.test.JSONRead.main(JSONRead.java:29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property type of "Company List" property is object, not an array.

Replace the line

```
JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Company List");
```

for:

```
JSONObject companyList = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Company List");
```

If you want to get the values ​​of this object, you can do the following:

```
JSONObject companyList = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Company List");
String company = companyList.getString("Company");
```

And remember to get the value of a property of a JSONObject which is an array, you must use the method [getJSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!..using getJSONObject, I am able to parse it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

companyList is a JSON Object, not an array. That's why you are getting that class cast exception.

Comment: Thanks, but how to extract the CompanyList components?